# Is there a spring-jpa method query to get all and sort them?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I want a JPA method query that does the equivalent of `select * from my_table order by my_col`. I can use the `findAll()` method to `select * from my_table` to get all columns and rows. I can declare and use `findAllBySomeColOrderByMyCol(someCol)` to get some rows and all columns and sort on `my_col`. What I can't find is `findAllOrderByMyCol()` to get all rows and columns and sort on one of the columns.

Does this really not exist? If not, what is the rationale? All are select *.

Answer (score 1):

My coworker helped me figure this out. The method is `findAllByOrderByMyCol()`. I promise I read https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.x/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods, which seem like the logical docs. The naming convention (using that first 'By') just didn't seem intuitive to me, and nothing in the docs really pointed it out.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: ??? the section you linked to has 24 examples all starting with 'findBy' including one for OrderBy. What do you mean by "nothing in the docs really pointed it out"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like me below, it should work:

```
import com.khaled.caterate.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository("userRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    List<User> findAllByFirstNameOrderByAverageMark(String firstName);
}
```